# how to delete a line from text file that is saved inside a string variable

Tags: c#, file

I have:

```
String yourName = "bob";
```

Now I want to delete bob from the textfile. How would I do this?

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\input"))
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\output"))
                            {
                                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                                {
                                    if (String.Compare(line, yourName) == 0)
                                        continue;

                                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

ive looked on this website as well as YouTube but nothing is there.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible. You need to loop through the lines and check if the current one contains your `string`. 
Here's an example of doing that:

```cs
string yourName = "bob";
string oldLine;
string newLine = null;
StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("C:\\input");
while ((oldLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null){
    if (!oldLine.Contains(yourName)) newLine += oldLine + Environment.NewLine;  
}
sr.Close();
File.WriteAllText("C:\\output", newLine);
```

**Note:** This will delete *all* lines **containing** the word `bob` 
Also, if you want to write to the same file, just use your input file instead of `output` at

```
File.WriteAllText("C:\\output", newLine);
```

I hope that helped!

Comment: Thumbs Up :) Thanks. Can you please take a look at my other question, it hasn't been answered in 5 days. Pls

Comment: @PearlPrincess No problem! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the replace method:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\input"))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\output"))
                        {
                            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                // if (String.Compare(line, yourName) == 0)
                                //    continue;

                                writer.WriteLine(line.Replace(yourName, "");
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

If the name is in the line, then it would be replaced with "" and you have deleted it. If the name is not in the line, then the replace method return the whole unchanged line.

[Show this link for more informations.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Does the value of `line` have to be exactly equal to the `yourName` string?

If your target is lines that contain the *yourName* string, then

```
if (line.Contains(yourName)) continue;
```

should suffice.

If however, you are looking to omit lines that are exactly the same as `yourName`, then

```
if (line?.ToLowerCase() == yourName?.ToLowerCase()) continue;
```

should be enough.